# bq show cames to return no Total Rows and Total Bytes since 2015-07-05 08:00 UTC

Tags: google-bigquery

`bq show` came to return no Total Rows and Total Bytes if the table is updated (via Streaming Insert) after 2015-07-05 08:00 UTC. Total Rows/Total Bytes are now blank.

Example response of `bq show [proj]:[ds].[table]` is as follows:

```
   Last modified                Schema               Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration
 ----------------- -------------------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------
  06 Jul 16:06:27   |- id: string
                    |- ...: string
                    |- ...: string
```

Will it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource) say that "This property is unavailable for tables that are actively receiving streaming inserts."  Not sure what would have changed on 2015-07-05, unless that was when streaming became active on those tables.  Would that fit what you've seen?

[The issue is tracked here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=209), if you want to star that to be notified if this behavior changes.

Comment: Yes, as you pointed out, streaming inserts were active on those tables.

I will star that issue when issue and feature request tracker is located after Google code.